# PostgreSQL function name as variable similar to TG_NAME?

Tags: postgresql, function, variables

Is there a special variable returning the name of a PostgreSQL **function** similar to special variable `TG_NAME` for **triggers**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of 9.4 I believe we have `PG_CONTEXT`:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inner_func() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
  stack text;
BEGIN
  GET DIAGNOSTICS stack = PG_CONTEXT;
  RAISE NOTICE E'--- Call Stack ---\n%', stack;
  RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

for parsing the context for function name, use `substring(stack from 'function (.*?) line')` as in 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016935/5315974

Comment: Ok, it's a good workaround. Of course I can put this into a separate function, return second line, maybe parse out the function name before. And maybe sometimes there is a FC_NAME variable in PostgreSQL.

Comment: this is the only way nowaday (btw quite recent - before the only solution was writing C function yourself) if you don't believe me - believe Erwin Brandstetter and Pavel Stehule (on the linked answer) :) First is a huge authority on SO, and the other is even recognised contributor https://www.postgresql.org/community/contributors/