# Equivalent of the "@@PROCID" system variable in SQL Server in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-migration

I'm migrating from a SQL Server database to opensource Postgres database.

SQL Server has a system variable called `@@PROCID`. I wanted to get its equivalent in PostgreSQL.

Comment: So what does `@@procid` do or represent?

Comment: [Microsoft doc for @@PROCID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/procid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). @@PROCID will return a scalar value of the object id (from the system catalog) for the current 'module' (as described by Microsoft) for stored procedures, user-defined functions, or triggers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting name of the current function inside of the function with plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611596/getting-name-of-the-current-function-inside-of-the-function-with-plpgsql)

Comment: Try: select pg_backend_pid()::text;